# How to obtain velocity and magnitude vectors of the optical flow field? I am using Lucas-Kande method of optical flow

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, opticalflow

I am working on the following code.

```
n=0;

folder = fileparts(which('viptraffic.avi'));

movieFullFileName = fullfile(folder, 'viptraffic.avi');

vidReader = VideoReader(movieFullFileName);

opticFlow = opticalFlowLK('NoiseThreshold',0.0039);

while hasFrame(vidReader)

   frameRGB = readFrame(vidReader);

   frameGray = rgb2gray(frameRGB);

   flow = estimateFlow(opticFlow,frameGray); 

   H=imag(flow)

   V=real(flow)

    frameWithFlow = getframe(gca);

    imshow(frameRGB);

    imshow(frameWithFlow.cdata)

    hold on

    plot(flow,'DecimationFactor',[5 5], 'ScaleFactor',10)

    hold off

    n=n+1;

end
```

Is there a way to get the optical flow estimates of velocity and magnitude for every optical flow field obtained in every image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`estimateFlow` returns an [opticalFlow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflow-class.html) object, which has properties for magnitude, phase, and velocity. So, in your case,`flow` is an `opticalFlow` object, not a complex array, and you cannot pass it to `real` and `imag`. Instead, use the properties of the object:

```
flow.Vx          % x component of velocity
flow.Vy          % y component of velocity
flow.Orientation % Phase
flow.Magnitude   % Magnitude
```

Comment: Well, with the above code, it is overwriting the value of Phase and Magnitude for each frame. To avoid this, I created a three-dimensional matrix as:-

nArrays=Vid_dur*Vid_frate; % Vid_dur is video duration and Vid_frate is video frame rate

threeD_Ori = zeros(Vid_height,Vid_width,nArrays,'single'); %Vid_height and Vid_width is video frames height and width.

Now, I am storing the data in matrix as

threeD_Ori(:,:,ii)=flow.Orientation;

But, it is giving in the incorrect matrix dimension error. How can I store the result?